# pre-defining classes not working when using pointers to classes

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a listener. Because of many cross-references I am trying to avoid including other classes and pre-define them

My listener looks as follows

.h

```
class Book
{
public:
    Book();
private:
    std::vector<MyListener *> listeners_;
    void Notify();
}
```

.cpp

```
Book::Book() {}

void Book::Notify() {

    MyListener *p_listener;

    for ( int i = 0; i < this->listeners_.size(); i++ ) {

        p_listener = listeners_[i];
        p_listener->Update();  // ERRORS THROWN HERE WHEN NOT INCLUDING LISTENER.H

    }
}
```

This all works fine when I include the listener.h file

```
#include "listener.h"
```

But when I instead pre-declare Listener it doesnt work

```
class Listener;
```

It gives me the two errors

```
C:\CPP\qtTradeSim\qtTradeSim\test\book.cpp:33: error: C2027: use of undefined type 'Listener'
C:\CPP\qtTradeSim\qtTradeSim\test\book.cpp:33: error: C2227: left of '->Update' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

Is there a way to avoid including the Listener header?

Comment: You need to forward-declare it in the header file, but actually include it in the implementation file.

Comment: @AmiTavory Right. Make your comment the solution.

Comment: @Rene Thanks. Searched if this was a duplicate, but couldn't find one, so answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose the compiler sees the following code:

```
class Listener;

std::vector<Listener*> pListeners;

// some code...

for(auto& pListener: pListeners) {
    pListener->update();
}
```

Note, how does the compiler see the `Listener` has a member function `update`? The symbol `update` could not be determined until the compiler see the `Listener` full declaration. Think if you used `update` with an argument missing, could the compiler capture this problem without seeing the declaration of `update`? Thus, it cannot translate the code. If you give a full declaration of the `Listener`, e.g.

```
class Listener {
public:
    Listener() { // some construction
    }
    void update() {
        // dosth
    }
};
```

The compiler could know the `update` method, its parameters, the return value, etc., and compile it happily.

Comment: makes sense having to pre-declare all the bits and pieces used. Lots of typing, though. too bad c++ cant just to some sort of pre-linking before compiling...

Answer (score 4):

In the header file of `class Book`, you should indeed use a forward declaration of `MyListener`, as the header only defines an `std::vector` of pointers to `MyListener` and does not need to know the full declaration of `MyListener`.

The implementation file of `class Book`, however, actually needs the full declaration of `MyListener`, as it calls its `update` method, so you would include `listener.h` in the implementation file of `class Book` instead of in the header file.

Comment: Ah, yes, that way round makes sense. Thanks for the quick answer